# Excel - Auto populate a cell based on exact adjacent value (when having same names)

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, dropdown, vlookup

I´m trying to get a cell to return the exact value adjacent to the item I´m searching for.

Here is an example of excel work

[image]

When introducing the second, or third ¨10¨, I want the H and G columns to show me the values next to the second or third ¨10¨, **not the first values**.

So. when introducing the second ¨10¨ I want column H to bring up Bonnie M and column G to bring up 55555.
Or **the third ¨10¨** to bring up **$B6** and **$C6**.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use a formula to retrieve the position of a selected item in a data validation dropdown. But you could use a list box (or combo box) (see [Add a list box or combo box to a worksheet in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-list-box-or-combo-box-to-a-worksheet-in-excel-579e1958-f7f6-41ae-ba0c-c83cc6e40878)). These will return the position of a selected item in a `Cell link`. Suppose we make `$F$2` the cell link, then for your 2nd `10` it will get the value `4`, so that `=INDEX($B$2:$B$10,$F$2,0)` will get you "Bonnie M", as requested.

Comment: so there´s no other way without using a combo box?
a formula based on Vlookup or Index and Match in the H or G columns?

Comment: To my knowledge, you will have to resort to a list box or combo box, as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to a solution with a support/help column in your data table, you may try the following solution.

Assume:

- Range A2:A10 is named **list_Num**
- Range B2:B10 is named **list_Name**
- Range C2:C10 is named **list_Serial**

I have added a new column called *Index* in column D. In cell D2, enter the following formula and drag it down to D10:

```
=A2&"-"&COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```

Then I named Range D2:D10 as **list_Index**.

Replace the dropdown list in column I with **list_Index**

Lastly, enter the following formula in Cell G2 and H2 irrespecitvely:

```
In cell G2 enter
=IFERROR(INDEX(list_Serial,MATCH(I2,list_index,0)),"")

In cell H2 enter
=IFERROR(INDEX(list_Name,MATCH(I2,list_index,0)),"")
```

Drag down the formula to apply across as shown below:

[image: Sol_Demo]

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Many thanks, very helpful.
Is there any way to make the formula in Index so that it cuts the -1 or -2 at the end?
This is the problem I´m having, the Number column in my real workbook has exact numbers, that are viewed and copied by others, they can´t have -x number at the end.
Example: 0987/11-2021/A ... if it shows 0987/11-2021/A-1 and 0987/11-2021/A-2 ... it will be confusing for the others that get in the excel list just to get the data and don´t know what´s going on.

Comment: @Gest can you please confirm if there will be duplicated values in your number column?

Comment: Column ¨I¨ will have duplicates as my number column (A) will always have duplicates, as I need to put in the number of a product that is coming several times a year. But the product has sometimes the same number, but different name and serial. So I need to input the number and get the exact name and serial. The helpful column helps, but the I column where I´m inputting data will show 1,2 or 3 at the end, and I need 1,2 or 3 to not show up as the clients need to see the exact number.

Comment: @Gest if you do not add the -1, -2 at the end of the number in the drop-down list, when you select the second 10 or the second 11, the formula can only return the first match, hence cannot resolve your issue.